# Only select images uploaded between 15:00:00 and 15:59:59

Tags: php

I use the following function to get all the images from a dir, but instead of putting all the images in the `$files` array, I would like to tweak it, so it only takes the images uploaded between 15:00:00 and 15:59:59 - today.

```
 function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg')) {
      $files = array();
      if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) { 
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
          if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
            $files[] = $file;
          }
        }
        closedir($handle);
      }
      return $files;
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to do it, and even less how to do it efficient since the folder has around 9000 images. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Note: All the images are named like this "Snapshot-20110910-103242.jpg" with date-time.

Comment: I'm assuming that putting the meta data about the image (e.g. created time) into a db table would be out of the question?

Comment: would like to avoid db in this case if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_files ($images_dir, $exts = array('jpg'), $start = '15:00:00', $end = '15:59:59', $usemtime = FALSE) {

    /**
    * str  $images_dir - Path to images directory
    * arr  $exts       - Permitted file extensions
    * str  $start      - Start time (H:i:s)
    * str  $end        - End time (H:i:s)
    * bool $usemtime   - Use file modified time instead of file created time
    */

    // Replace \ with / and strip trailing slashes so we can easily create a valid file path
    $images_dir = rtrim(str_replace('\\','/',$images_dir),'/');

    // Get start/end times
    $starttime = strtotime($start);
    $endtime = strtotime($end);

    // Array to hold the results
    $files = array();

    // Open the directory and loop it
    if ($handle = opendir($images_dir)) { 

        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE) {

            // Get this file's extension and created/modified time
            $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
            $filetime = ($usemtime) ? filemtime("$images_dir/$file") : filectime("$images_dir/$file");

            // Check the file's extension and created or modified time
            // I have removed the first $extension check because it is unnecessary)
            if (in_array($extension,$exts) && $filetime >= $starttime && $filetime <= $endtime) {
                $files[] = $file;
            }

        }

        // Close the directory
        closedir($handle);

    }

    // Return the list
    return $files;

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Muchos gracias. And even with comments to help me on the way, i salute you! :-)

Comment: Any idea why i can't change: 
$start = '15:00:00' 
into 
$start = $starttid
in function get_files() and then have $starttid defined before as $starttid = '15:00:00';

Comment: @Troels Because PHP will not let you do that. From the PHP manual: `The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.` - [read this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php). Just pass `$startid` as an argument. Also, I realised there was a slight inefficiency in this and I have changed it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and the readings. I'm realising my knowledge about php is way smaller than i remembered. 
How can i pass it as an argument, i can't seem to get my head around it?

Comment: The same way you pass any other argument. E.g. `$list = get_files('/myimagesdir',array('jpg'),$startid);`. You may consider using the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array or the [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword to fetch values from outside the function, but this will reduce the portability of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the glob function](http://php.net/manual/function.glob.php) to filter alot of the images. So, the glob call you'd use would be the following:

`glob( $images_dir . '/Snapshot-20110912-15????.jpg' );`

Answer (score 0):

Use [scandir](http://uk.php.net/scandir) to get a list of all files in the directory, then loop that array doing something like this to get matching filenames

```
function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg'))
{
    $wantedFiles = array();
    $scannedFiles = scandir($images_dir);
    $todaysDate = date('Ymd');

    foreach ($scannedFiles AS $file)
    {
        $filenameBits = explode('-', $file);

        // Get the info we want
        $numFilenameBits = count($filenameBits);
        $fileData = explode('.', $filenameBits[$numFilenameBits - 1]);

        if (in_array($fileData[1], $exts) && $filenameBits[$numFilenameBits - 2] == $todaysDate && $fileData[0] > 150000 && $fileData[0] < 155959)
            $wantedFiles[] = $file;
    }

    return $wantedFiles;
}
```

Comment: Doable, but not very scalable.

Comment: This will not work correctly if filenames contain hyphens '-' characters.

Comment: @Aleks: He said they didn't. Updated to use last pieces of the filename now though. Also @Jon, why not very scalable? I was under the impression `scandir()` takes less time to run than looping through `readdir()`.

Answer (score 0):

This'll get the file's "last modified" timestamp, and figure out if it was last modified during the 3pm hour.

```
$stat = stat($images_dir . '/' . $file);

$mtime = $stat[9];
if (date('G', $stat[9]) == 15) {
    ... file was last modified sometime during 3-4pm
}
```

Comment: It needs to be a bit smarter than that: time alone is not enough, he also needs the date to be today's date.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the file name, in this case Snapshot-20110910-103242.jpg and use substr to get the time on the file name like this:

```
$var = "Snapshot-20110910-103242.jpg";
$var = substr($var, -10,6);
```

Now that you have the time (103242), just use a if statement to check it the image was uploaded between 15:00:00 and 15:59:59